# Iterating through an Amazon-specific XDocument

Tags: c#, xml, amazon-web-services, xpath

I'm working with the Amazon Advertising API, which returns XML as demonstrated in this fiddle: http://xopusfiddle.net/27NxH/

I'm looking to get the value of the item as offered by Amazon, where it exists. In theory, the following should return an XML node with the name of `Amount` and the value of `9980`

```
string uri = "redacted" + isbn;
string signedUri = helper.Sign(uri);
WebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.Create(signedUri);
WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
xDoc.Load(response.GetResponseStream());
var testvar = xDoc.SelectSingleNode("/ItemLookupResponse/Items/Item/ItemAttributes/ListPrice");
```

However, `testvar` returns `null`. The same occurs when I attempt to return an `XmlNodeList` also.

I've checked that there is indeed an XML document loaded (there is), and I've noticed that the following will return the correct node (`Amount`) with a value of `9980`:

```
XmlNode aznPriceNode = xDoc.DocumentElement.ChildNodes.Item(1).ChildNodes.Item(1).ChildNodes.Item(8).ChildNodes.Item(10).ChildNodes.Item(0);
```

However, hardcoding such a path is a terrible idea, and doesn't always work since the XML document might not always contain a `ListPrice` entry.

Why doesn't XPath work in this instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to add the namespace.

```
const string xpath = "/x:ItemLookupResponse/x:Items/x:Item/x:ItemAttributes/x:ListPrice";
XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
XmlNamespaceManager ns = new XmlNamespaceManager(new NameTable());
xDoc.Load(response.GetResponseStream());
ns.AddNamespace("x", xDoc.DocumentElement.NamespaceURI);
var testvar = xDoc.SelectSingleNode(xpath, ns);
```

Comment: Why is the namespace so necessary? Could I, for example, edit the XmlDocument in memory to remove the namespace? I ask this because the namespace has a date in it, and evidently may change at any given point rendering my application useless.

Comment: I have updated the solution to load the document first, then use `xDoc.DocumentElement.NamespaceURI` to get the namespace Url directly from the document.